# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, django, mechanize

I have inherited a python script that is throwing the following error:

```
root        : ERROR    Unexpected exception encountered in application 'ImagesForWeb'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/columbiancommon/scaffolding/consoleapp.py", line 169, in run_safe
    self.run(**kwargs)
  File "/var/scripts/ImagesForWeb/imagesforweb.py", line 102, in run
    gallery = columbiancommon.EllingtonPhotoGallery(configobj = self.cmgr)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/columbiancommon/ellington/photogallery.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.Reload()
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/columbiancommon/ellington/photogallery.py", line 128, in Reload
    self.SetStatus(self.status)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/columbiancommon/ellington/photogallery.py", line 68, in SetStatus
    self.SetControl("status", [self.status.encode('utf-8', 'replace')])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I'm pretty new to Python and haven't quite developed the debugging skills to know how to solve this issue yet.

Here's the code snippet from `photogallery.py` that is refrenced in the above error:

```
def SetStatus(self, status):
    """
    Sets the publication status of this photo gallery.

    Expects to be set to an integer constant, shortcuts include::

        EllingtonPhotoGallery.LIVE
        EllingtonPhotoGallery.DRAFT
        EllingtonPhotoGallery.DELETED
        EllingtonPhotoGallery.UNREVIEWED

    """
    if(not isinstance(status, int)):
        raise EllingtonMechanizeException("Unexpected status value.  Please use a status constant.")
    self.status = status
    self.SetControl("status", [self.status.encode('utf-8', 'replace')])
```

This is the SetControl method that is within the scaffolding.py

```
def SetControl(self, control_name, control_value_unclean):
    """
    Raw access to the mechanize method of setting controls to specific values.

    **WARNING** Do not use this unless you have a really good reason to do so-- `EllingtonMechanizeScaffolding.SetControlToValue`
    and `EllingtonMechanizeScaffolding.SetControlToValueSafe` are much more elegant solutions.

    :Parameters:
        - `control_name`: The name of the control you're trying to assign a value to.
        - `control_value_unclean`: The value to assign to said control.  Either a boolean value, 

    """
    self.browser[control_name] = control_value_unclean
    return True
```

I believe it's the line that says `self.SetControl("status", [self.status.encode('utf-8', 'replace')])`
 that is throwing the error however I can't tell why the error is ocuring. The code has been working since I inherited it 6 months ago and it has not been altered on my end.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not Python 3.x, since Ellington and Django are Python 2.x only.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that this code worked unchanged for six months. Save for a weird property or `__{g,s}etattr__` hack that makes `self.status = status` and `self.status` behave unusual, the code you show here either throws an exception or tries to `.encode` an object that is an instance of `int`.

Comment: And even if self.status was a unicode object, the 'replace' in self.status.encode('utf-8', 'replace') is evil because it would conceal a very bad `unicode` object, e.g. one containing an unpaired surrogate.

Answer (score 8):

You first assert `status` to be an instance of `int`, and then you try to use `encode` method, which it doesn't have, because it's a `unicode` method. If you want to convert the integer to string, use `unicode(self.status)`. Then you can use `encode` on it, though you most likely shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try. Also, why do you say "you most likely shouldn't"?

Comment: @bigmike7801: Have you looked at the SetControl method to see what it expects?

Comment: I have added the code for SetControl to my question above but am unable to see anything within it that may be causing the issue.

Comment: @bigmike7801: SetControl is NOT causing the issue, issue happens in its CALLER. You are supposed to be looking at what it expects ... """Either a boolean value,  """ -- there seems to be something missing there from the docstring. It is being passed a one-element list containing a nonsense expression. As others have said, this code can never have worked properly. Either it has been changed or something else has happened to make it be called for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

use `repr()` function. This function can handle unicode, utf, null and int. Good part of this function is that this function does not lose any value when converting unicode(like `encode('utf-8')` does) or ascii to string. Also this function provide size limits for the representations so you have more flexibility on your object.